# Incompatible Types error binary to decimal

Tags: java

I am writing this code and I can't figure out why I can't get rid of the incompatible types error.

```
private String digits;

public String binaryToDecimal() {  
    int sum = 0;
    if(base==2) {  
        for(int i=0;i<digits.length();i++) {     
            if(digits.charAt(i)== '1')
                sum =+ (int)(Math.pow(2,(digits.length()-1-i)));
        }
        return  sum;
    }
    else 
        return "Not a binary number!";
}//end method
```

I do not know what to do so can someone help me?

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: What is the method's return type?  What are the types of `digits` and `sum`?

Comment: Um, `+=` instead of `=+`?

Answer (score 2):

You have basically two problems.

Your method is declared to return a String:

```
public String binaryToDecimal()
```

But you are trying to return an int:

```
int sum = 0;
...
return sum;
```

That is the reason for the incompatible types error. If you want to return a String you can solve this like the following:

```
return String.valueOf(sum);
```

The second problem is you have a typo on your compound assignment:

```
sum =+ (int) ... ;
```

It should be:

```
sum += (int) ... ;
```